# Computational complexity of LambdaMART

Tags: time-complexity, machine-learning

- Could someone provide a general estimate of the average (time) complexity of the LambdaMART learning-to-rank algorithm?
- A particular implementation of LambdaMART is known as XGBRanker. It uses XGBoosts as the underlying model to learn to predict relevance scores. Is it possible to derive a better estimate for this particular implementation?
- Please, provide the necessary citations/sources on which the complexity estimation is based

EDIT: Resources on LambdaRANK and LambdaMART

- [https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~nie/IFT6255/Books/Learning-to-rank.pdf](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Enie/IFT6255/Books/Learning-to-rank.pdf)
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/02/MSR-TR-2010-82.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you add some links to  references defining LambdaMART, it will be easier to help you and answer your question!

Comment: Ok, I have edited the post

Comment: Please don't use 'EDIT:'.  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Please use a full citation/reference (title, authors, where published), not just a link to a PDF.  We want the question to remain meaningful even if the link stops working, and we want others with a similar question about those papers to be able to find this by search.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Running time as a function of which parameters?  Please provide background.  What have you come up with?  Please show your progress.